# How can I get the deepest nested object in React.js?

Tags: reactjs

There is something called each_devices variable.

```
const each_devices = object_device_value.map((e) => ({ e }));

console.log(each_devices);
console.log(each_devices[0]);
```

write like this
In the console you can see the structure like in the picture.

[image]
[image]

However, I write like this

```
　　　　　　const each_devices = object_device_value.map((e) => ({ e }));



   console.log(each_devices);
   console.log(each_devices[0]);
   console.log(each_devices[0].e);
```

The screen looks like a photo.

[image]

How can I get the deepest nested object?
Like

```
    {
        "entity_id": "camera_3",
        "object_id": "Z104E0A3476D0",
        "home": "api/services/home",
        "away": "api/services/away",
        "image": "services/camera_proxy/camera_3",
        "live_stream": "services/camera_proxy_stream/camera_3",
        "mode": "Home",
        "room_name": "Garage",
        "state": "Home",
        "stream": "services/camera_proxy_stream/camera_3",
        "is_failed": false,
        "rank": 0,
        "disabled": false
    },
```

Comment: You destructured `e` in your second example, so I would expect `console.log(each_devices[0].e);` to fail.  What does `each_devices[0]` look like?

Comment: Thank you. please watch the second photo. line 116. you can see structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whatever you are doing is correct. However in react during the first render the data/property may not be available yet. You haven't shared the entire component, I assume you are trying to log inside the component and not inside any useEffect.

It is always best to check if the property is available first before trying to access it. something like,

```
console.log(each_devices[0] && each_devices[0].e);
```

this will help you debug!

Comment: thank you. it work. how can I utlize this answer for map function? like             {each_devices.map((item,i) => 
                  <div key={i} className="discover_device col-12"></div>
            )}

Comment: I got same error with Map function.

Comment: same like {each_devices && each_devices.map((item,i) => <div key={i} className="discover_device col-12"></div> )}